# Radiation pattern and signal strength of navigation satellite antennas

Tags: navigation, reference-request, communication-satellite, gnss, antenna

Where can I find the actual radiation pattern and signal strength of transmitting antennas used by GNSS navigation satellites/constellations (GPS, GLONASS, IRNSS, etc)?

Answer (score 9):

Exact [radiation patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pattern) and [gain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_gain) (you're probably not asking about [signal strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_strength) since that depends on distance which isn't constant) will vary across all the different [GNSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_navigation) contellations, even individual generations / blocks of same systems, but for a fairly detailed analysis of GPS blocks, you can refer to e.g. [GPS Space Service Volume: Ensuring Consistent Utility Across GPS Design Builds for Space Users](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=20150011650).

For example, side lobe gain patterns could look like this (for GPS Block IIF and Block IIR-M):

[image: GPS Block IIF and Block IIR-M side lobe gain patterns]

And hemispherical gain patterns could look like this (For GPS Block IIR):

[image: GPS constellation hemispherical gain patterns]

You can find more relevant information e.g. by searching the [NASA Technical Report Server](http://ntrs.nasa.gov) (NTRS).

Comment: Thanks @TidalWave.  Are there any other resources, where I can find more similar data for other constellations.???

Comment: @akum I know that [InsideGNSS](http://www.insidegnss.com) covered a lot of this, and on top of already mentioned NTRS you may also want to search for technical reports over at [AIAA](http://www.aiaa.org/).