How can GPS provide a spacecraft's attitude?
According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statevector

Orbital state vectors are vectors of position and velocity that,
together with their time, uniquely determine the state of an orbiting
body in astrodynamics or in celestial dynamics.

If the state vector is known, the spacecraft’s ballistic trajectory can be calculated.
However, if the spacecraft’s controller wants to alter the trajectory using thrusters, the attitude of the spacecraft must also be known,
GPS can provide a spacecraft’s position and time. With successive fixes (or Doppler measurements), velocity can be added. Thus, GPS alone can provide the state vector. But without additional instrumentation (such as a star tracker), can GPS also provide attitude determination? Or does it require an absolute attitude sensor?

Commenting instead of answering because I don't understand the methods well enough to say much, but: yes.  See for example GNSS-Based Attitude Determination Techniques—A Comprehensive Literature Survey from 2020. Maybe someone can make an answer out of it.

See also https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37244/6944

@OrganicMarble ... it turns out there are methods of attitude determination different than those described in the linked question. That method uses differential fixes from antennae located on the extremities of the craft. Another method uses carrier wave phase differences. Since the wavelength is shorter than the fix precision, attitude can be determined much more accurately.

It's a yes or no question, right? And are you saying you already knew the answer when you posted the question?

@OrganicMarble ... No, that's not what I said. After I posted the question I kept reading because I thought the problem interesting.

Good, because I despise stump-the-chump questions. If you actually edit the question and not just the title I'll retract the duplicate vote.

@OrganicMarble ... you lost me. I don't understand what part of the question you find despicable so I doubt I could edit it to your satisfaction. If you feel the question could be improved, please feel free to edit it. I think the technology is important and the topic is of interest to many of this site's readers.

@Woody I think Marble just wants the question body to be changed to reflect the title change. As it is, the question body text is still ultimately "can GPS provide attitude determination"
